# Vowel checker always returns zero instead of vowel count

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

This program is a vowel checker that accepts arguments from the commandline, but its not working properly. Why does the count always return 0? What is wrong here?

```
import sys

string = sys.argv[1:]

def is_vowel(c):
    vowel = (c == 'a' or c == 'e' or c == 'i' or c == 'o' or c == 'u' or c == 'y')
    return vowel



def count_vowels(string): 
    count = 0
    for v in string: 
        if is_vowel(v) == True:
            count += 1 
    return count

print(count_vowels(string))
```

EDIT: I have found that the program works when I change string = sys.argv[1:] to string = sys.argv[1]

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: could you show the sample input and output

Comment: `def is_vowel(c): return c in set('aeiouAEIOU')` You should account for uppercase letters, or call `string = string.lower()` before passing.

Comment: @KalyanReddy input crazy, output zero

Comment: for the input crazy, i got 2 as answer @Linda Acquaviva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string` is a `list` because you are setting it to `sys.argv[1:]` which is a slice of `argv`. So when you iterate over `string`, you are actually iterating over its elements and not an actual `str`.

If you want to do multiple inputs, you can try:

```
for i in sys.argv[1:]:
  print(count_vowels(i))
```

Comment: Okay thanks for this. How can I give my program multiple items then, instead of just one.

Comment: I entered what you gave me, Told me invalid syntax

Comment: I was missing a colon, sorry @LindaAcquaviva

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
 string = sys.argv[1:]



def is_vowel(c):
    vowel = (c == 'a' or c == 'e' or c == 'i' or c == 'o' or c == 'u' or c == 'y')
    return vowel



def count_vowels(string): 
    count = 0
    for v in string: 
        if is_vowel(v) == True:
            count += 1 
    return count

for i in string:
    print(count_vowels(i))
```

Comment: I understand about the lower, however that part is not my concern, please look at the edit

Comment: when you use sys.argv[1:] you are actually returning a list instead of a string

Comment: How can I instead give the program two words for example? Instead of crazy, maybe crazy boy

Comment: keep them in quotes

Comment: you could have asked this in question properly. anyway..happy that your doubt is solved

Comment: I tried adding the words in quotes, but it only did the first word, so it returned the amount of values in the first word...